# What is to tmf as KR is to KO?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stable-homotopy

The $E_\infty$-ring spectrum $KU$ of complex K-theory carries a canonical involution induced from complex conjugation of complex vector bundles. The homotopy fixed points of this $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action is $KO$ and the corresponding $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivariant cohomology theory is [KR-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KR-theory) ("real K-theory").

A pleasant conceptual account of this state of affairs that puts it into the bigger context of [chromatic homotopy theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/chromatic+homotopy+theory) was given in the appendix of

- Tyler Lawson, Niko Naumann, *Strictly commutative realizations of diagrams over the Steenrod algebra and topological modular forms at the prime 2* ([arXiv:1203.1696](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.1696))

which is usefully amplified and further expanded on in section 3 of

- Akhil Mathew, *The homology of $tmf$* ([arXiv:1305.6100](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6100))

and section 2 of

- Akhil Mathew, *The homotopy groups of $TMF$*, talk notes ([pdf](http://math.mit.edu/~sglasman/tmfhomotopy.pdf))

Namely, $KU$ equipped with its involution appears, via Goerss-Hopkins-Miller, as the $E_\infty$-structure sheaf on the "moduli stack of 1-dimension tori", which is just $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{G}_m}\simeq \mathbf{B}\mathbb{Z}_2$.

The main theorem (1.2) of Lawson-Naumann above is that the inclusion $KO \to KU$ obtained this way as the image under forming global sections of the canonical double cover of $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{G}_m}$ is (at prime 2) the restriction of a similar inclusion of [topological modular forms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tmf) $tmf \to tmf_1(3)$.

Discussion of such finite covers of the moduli stack of elliptic curves goes back to a result by Mahowald-Rezk and a similar realization of $tmf$ as a homotopy fixed-point spectrum induced by a cover of elliptic curves with "level N structure" is in

- Vesna Stojanoska, *Duality for Topological Modular Forms* ([arXiv:1105.3968](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3968))

this time the group acting is $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ (for $N= 2$).

Now I suppose if I dig through all this a bit more it will all become clear, but right now the following question seems as obvious as its explicit statement seems to be missing from all of the above:

**Question.** What exactly is to the [real-oriented cohomology theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/real-oriented%20cohomology%20theory) $KR$ as $KO$ is to $tmf$?

Actually I have a more concrete question that I am trying to understand, but that requires the following 2-sentence introduction:

the homotopy fiber of $B String \to B O$ should be equivalent to $Pic(KU)_{\leq 3}$. By the argument in section 8 of

- Matthew Ando, Andrew J. Blumberg, David Gepner, *Twists of K-theory and TMF* ([arXiv:1002.3004](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3004))

this should induce a homomorphism of connective spectra of the form

$$
  T: Pic(KU)_{\leq 3} \longrightarrow GL_1(tmf)
  \,.
$$

On the left we have a quotient map $Pic(KU)_{\leq 3} \to (Pic(KU)_{\leq 3})//\mathbb{Z}_2$ induced by the above involution, hence essentially passing to KR-theory.

**Question.** In which sense would $T$ naturally descend along this quotient? Specifically, is there a ring spectrum $Q$ with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action whose homotopy fixed points is $tmf$ and such that $T$ naturally descends to 
$$
  (Pic(KU)_{\leq 3})//\mathbb{Z}_2 \longrightarrow GL_1(Q)//\mathbb{Z}_2
$$

?

Or else, if all this is misled: what IS the natural way to bring in the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on the right, compatible with KR-theory?

Comment: What about the remark in the end of the introduction of Mahowald-Rezk? Hu and Kriz (http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hukriz.pdf‎) have constructed real oriented theories based on $E(n)$, which are usually denoted $ER(n)$. Now $ER(1) = KO_{(2)}$ and $ER(2)$ is very much like $TMF_0(3)$. They then make the comment "Presumably the construction of [HK01] can be carried out to construct a “real” version of $TMF_1(3)$"

Comment: We (Gerd Laures and I) have now used this construction in [arxiv:1403.7301](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7301). There were choices involved, however. For us the equivariant homotopy type was not so important. So my question would be: Does Hill-Lawson's paper [arxiv:1312.7394](http://arxiv.org/abs/312.7394) together with Elmendorf's theorem fix the equivariant homotopy type?

Comment: Drew and Martin, thanks, so indeed TMF_0(3) is the Z/2Z homotopy fixed points of TMF_1(3); but what about TMF itself? And the compatibility with the action on KU? (Maybe I am missing somehting obvious here...) I was guessing that for TMF itself the construction by Lawson-Naumann is going in the right direction. It bothered me that it only worked 2-locally, but maybe that shouldn't bother me too much. Hm...

Comment: You should really have a look at the Hill-Lawson paper, correct link: [arxiv:1312.7394](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7394).
The moduli stacks of curves with level $N$ structures and subgroup $\Gamma$ are typically only covers of ${\mathcal M}_{ell}[\frac 1N]$, so e.g. for level 3-structures one has to invert the prime 3 (but does not need to work 2-locally). Also for $\Gamma_1(N)$ and $N>2$ the cover is an affine scheme. I don't think there is such a "nice" $\mathbb Z/2$-cover of ${\mathcal M}_{ell}$ in the literature.

Comment: I am hoping to see the cover given by the inversion involution  on elliptic curves. Is there a subtlety about this obvious idea that I am missing? The 8-fold cover which gives $tmf_1(3)$ quotients to a double cover, I need to understand what that is explicitly.

Comment: Or putting on the string theorist hat: what orientifold string physics (where KR-theory appears as the home of the D-brane charges) suggests is that the involution on the worldsheet elliptic curves should be what in physics is called the "worldsheet parity operator" -- which reverses worldsheet orientation...

Comment: Urs, so far as I know there is not a natural double cover of tmf exactly like you request. One reason is that most of the natural etale covers of the moduli stack come from subgroups of GL_2(Z/N). The natural negation on elliptic curves corresponds to the element -1, which is a square and hence inside any index 2 subgroup.

Comment: Another possible answer might be that, in certain circumstances, we might end up with $Tmf$ (with some primes inverted) as the $G$-fixed points of some extension, and $G$ might act on some finite product of things related to $K$-theory rather than a single term.  These kinds of situations do exist (corresponding to "evaluation at the cusps").  However, this doesn't even come close to answering your question about the relationship between Pic and GL_1.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I am reading Hill-Lawson now with some effect. Maybe I should first consider my question with tmf replaced by just Tate K-theory, to warm up. You mention the open question of generalizing the Witten genus: what would even be a plausible replacement of the domain $MO\langle 8\rangle$ as we pass to some cover of $\mathcal{M}_{\overline{ell}}$ for the codomain?

Comment: @UrsSchreiber For $Tmf_1(3)$, Nitu Kitchloo pointed out to me the following possible weakening of String manifolds as a possibility: instead of manifolds with vanishing $w_1$, $w_2$, and $p_1/2$, consider manifolds with vanishing $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_4$ (this third being the mod-2 reduction of $p_1/2$ when the first two vanish).  Some extensions might admit highly structured Spin orientations, $MSU$ orientations, $MU$ orientations.  I don't think the story is clear yet.

Comment: Thanks again. Here is another thought, but I need two sentences to prepare: So my above question was motivated from string theory considerations: there it is known that the general type II string orientifold background is controled by KR-theory receiving its twists from the "orientifolding" $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-bundle on spacetime; and general lore suggests that this scenario has a "lift to M-theory" where K-theory is replaced by elliptic cohomology. Hence my question. But now the type II "lifts to M-theory" are known as "F-theory" (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/F-theory) and that theory...

Comment: ... and that theory is famously controled by a $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-bundle (being the monodromy bundle of an elliptic fibration). An old argument due to Ashoke Sen (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/F-theory#RelationToOrientifolds) says that the inversion involution inside $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ induces the orientifolding, hence that this $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-local system is indeed the F-theoretic analog of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-twist on $\mathrm{KU}$. But now by Mahowald-Rezk and then your work, we have that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ or at least the quotient $SL_2(\hat {\mathbb{Z}})$ is the twist of...

Comment: ...is the twist of an equivariant version of $tmf$. By this story, I shouldn't be fighting the fact that the literature discusses realizations of $tmf$ as $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$-homotopy fixed points, but should maybe rather be embracing it. (Sorry for the lengthy comment, hope you see what I mean; a decent discussion of this would have to break out of this puny comment functionality here.)

Comment: I see now that essentialy what I just suggested had already been conjectured on p. 3 in Igor Kriz, Hisham Sati, "Type II string theory and modularity" http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0501060

Comment: As has been mentioned, the spectrum $KO$ is entirely determined by the $C_2$-action on $K_\mathbf{R}$; similarly, $ko = \tau_{\geq 0} k_\mathbf{R}^{hC_2}$. The spectrum $k_\mathbf{R}$ is $BP\mathbf{R}\langle 1 \rangle$, so it is the "first step" towards (chromatically) constructing $BP\mathbf{R}$. There is a conjectural analogue of this $\mathbf{R}$eal spectrum at odd primes, which is supposed to be a genuine $C_p$-spectrum $BP_{C_p}$ which satisfies a list of desiderata. In any case, one can attempt to attack the simpler question of constructing a genuine $C_p$-spectrum...

Comment: ... $BP_{C_p}\langle 1 \rangle$ which satisfies an analogue of these conditions. I think Dylan Wilson has shown that the spectrum $tmf(2) = \tau_{\geq 0} Tmf(2)$, along with its $C_3 \subsetneq \Sigma_3 = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_2)$-action, has the desired properties at $p=3$. From the perspective of equivariant homotopy theory, it seems like $Tmf(2)$ is therefore the appropriate analogue of $K_\mathbf{R}$. This is related to the idea that formal $\mathbf{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$-modules tell us about height $(p-1)$ phenomena, which is why the appropriate "height $2$" analogue of $K_\mathbf{R}$...

Comment: ...at $p=3$ is supposed to be dictated by the geometry of the moduli of formal $\mathbf{Z}_3[\zeta_3]$-modules of formal $\mathbf{Z}_3[\zeta_3]$-height one.

Answer (score 12):

Let $G$ be a finite group. Then one has a symmetric monoidal, stable $\infty$-category of (genuine) $G$-spectra. Inside here is a subcategory obtained by localization (it behaves more like a completion) at the commutative algebra object $\mathbb{D}(G_+)$ where $\mathbb{D}$ denotes Spanier-Whitehead duality. This subcategory is equivalent to the $\infty$-category of spectra equipped with a $G$-action, i.e., $\mathrm{Fun}(BG, \mathrm{Sp})$. Let's call such $G$-spectra Borel-equivariant.

The $\mathbb{Z}/2$-spectrum $KR$ representing Atiyah's $KR$-theory for $\mathbb{Z}/2$-spaces is Borel-equivariant, and it comes from the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on complex $K$-theory $KU$ given by complex conjugation. As a result, $KR$ can be constructed as an equivariant spectrum one one knows the conjugation action on $KU$.

Given any faithful $G$-Galois extension of $E_\infty$-ring spectra $R \to R'$ in the sense of [Rognes](http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/serien/e/mpi_mathematik/2005/79.pdf), one can thus construct a genuine $G$-spectrum, which is the Borel-equivariant spectrum that comes from the $G$-action on $R'$. Like $KR$, these genuine $G$-spectra will have trivial Tate constructions. For $TMF$ with a prime $p$ inverted, there are a number of Galois extensions that come from taking covers of the moduli stack of elliptic curves by imposing some sort of level structure. Each of these Galois extensions thus gives a genuine $G$-spectrum that one can think of as analogous to the real $K$-theory $KR$.

(Essentially, the content of this answer is that while there analogs of $KR$ for $TMF$, there is no new information that they contain that you have not cited, since $KR$ is determined entirely in terms of the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on $KU$.)